# Run-Time error '424' : Object Required in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

```
Sub Calculate()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim v As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    i = expression.Ceiling(Worksheets("Calculator").Cells(10, 4).Value / 7, 1)
    v = Worksheets("Calculator").Cells(13, 4).Value
    d = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value - Worksheets("Calculator").Cells(10, 4).Value
    Do Until v >= Worksheets("Calculator").Cells(16, 4).Value
         v = v + Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
         d = d + 7
         i = i + 1
    Loop
    Worksheets("Calculator").Cells(10, 6).Value = d
End Sub
```

In this code I try to get the value in Cell D10 divide it by 7 and get its ceiling but it says the error in the title and highlights this line. Can someone help me out? This is my first time using code in Excel but I had experience with other languages such as Lua, C++ and I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: What is 'expression'?

Comment: What is `expression` an instance of?  For a generic function use `WorksheetFunction.Ceiling()`